# SQL match between two tables and further match between columns

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have two tables: Master Data and Sample Data.

Master Data has columns "Key", "from date", "to date", "PayTM"

Sample Data has columns "Key", "creation date", "PayTS"

I'm trying to get the code to do this:

1. For every "key" match between two tables >
2. Determine if "creation date" falls between "from date" and "to date" >
3. IF YES, show that match/record (from Sample Data table) including PayTM and PayTS. 
   IF NO, dont show the record. (And go through all of the matches performing steps 2 and 3)

This is what I have so far, but it's showing records that don't match...I tried replacing WHERE NOT EXISTS with EXISTS but it's giving me an error. My sql coding skills are very basic and I'm struggling with trying to make the code work past this for some reason.

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM [Sample Data] as cd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [Master Data] as md
              WHERE cd.Key = md.Key AND
                    md.[Creation Date] BETWEEN md.From Date and md.To Date
             );
```

Comment: Read about joins

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by simple join. Something like:

```
SELECT cd.* , md.*
FROM [Sample Data] as cd, [Master Data] as md
 WHERE cd.Key = md.Key AND
                    cd.[Creation Date] BETWEEN md.[From Date] and md.[To Date];
```

Note: The above query is pseudo query just to high-light idea.

Comment: When I tried to apply this solution, it pulls in all the data records for that match between "Key" and the dates. I only need it to pull those matching records from Sample Data but also include "PayTM" from Master data only. Do I do this by saying SELECT cd.*, md.[PayTM]    ?

Comment: Also, if i wanted to add a column with that query which would look at "PayTS" and "PayTM", and if those two matched it would say "yes" and if they didn't match it would say "No"....is it possible to do that with sql?

Comment: @KateLO You can simply use `md.PayTM` is select part instead of `md.*`. If you can share the exact query then I can modify it. I dont think query shown in OP is write because it refers `[Creation Date]` in md which is not correct.

Comment: I just tested the code you provided and it works, the only thing im trying to figure out now is how I can get the code to add a new column value for each record which compares PayTM and PayTS and if they match it would say "Yes" and if not "No". Would that have to be an add in to the code or something completely different?

Comment: @KateLO You can use a CASE statement in your select part. It would be something like `SELECT cd.*, CASE when md.PayTM = cd.PayTS  then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as SameValue FROM [Sample Data] as cd, [Master Data] as md
 WHERE cd.Key = md.Key AND
                    cd.[Creation Date] BETWEEN md.[From Date] and md.[To Date];'

Answer (score 0):

I think this should handle it.

```
select
        x.key_
       ,x.paytm
       ,x.payts
from(
    select
            md.key   as key_
           ,cd.paytm as paytm
           ,cd.payts as payts
           ,case when md.creation_date between md.from_date and md.to_date
                 then 'goodie'
                 else 'baddie'
            end as the_test  

    from
            [master data] md
    inner join
            [sample data] cd
            on cd.key = md.key
)x
where
        x.the_test != 'baddie'
```